# How to fix error including autoNumeric to laravel / blade / jQuery / Bootstrap project?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I try to install autoNumeric from
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Numbers-Currency-Formatting-Plugin-autoNumeric/

In my laravel 5.7/ blade / jQuery v3.3.1 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 app and for this in my blade form where I want to use autoNumeric
I included ref to AutoNumeric.js file:

```
...
@endsection

@section('scripts')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/select2.min.css') }}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/select2.full.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/AutoNumeric/AutoNumeric.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/formfile.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"></script>
...
```

I uploaded 8 files into /public/js/AutoNumeric subdirectory from /autoNumeric-master/src of uploaded zip file

and when jquery is inited I added line :

```
$('#selling_range').autoNumeric('init');
```

and I got error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and clicking on the error I see next error code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmPEx.jpg

Is it wrong way of including this library and which is valid ?

**UPDATED 2 :**
I tried to modify declarations as :

```
new AutoNumeric( '#selling_range', null );
```

but anyway I got error:

```
AutoNumeric.js:49 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and in console error was pointing to lines :

```
//TODO Prevent having to enter relative path in the js files (ie. using `./AutoNumericHelper` instead of just `AutoNumericHelper`) (cf. http://moduscreate.com/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/)
import AutoNumericHelper from './AutoNumericHelper';
import AutoNumericEnum from './AutoNumericEnum';
```

as in my  printscreen above. How to fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following structure in order to initialized an AutoNumeric object.

```
new AutoNumeric('#selling_range', {options});
```

Where options can be null or any of the ones included in their library. Now, if you want to go through a list of elements and initialize an AutoNumeric object for each one of them, you could do something like the code below.

```
$('.elements').each(function() {
    new AutoNumeric(this, {options});
});
```

In order for this to work, you need to use the following version. Also, there is no need to import `AutoNumericHelper` or `AutoNumericEnum`, for it to work.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autonumeric@4.1.0"></script>
```

Comment: Hello! Please, look at UPDATED 2.

Comment: Check if you are using the newest version.
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autonumeric@4.1.0"></script>`